# eval path to java does not exist

Tags: java, tomcat, eval

I'm getting an error when trying to start tomcat that says 
`eval /var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java: No such file or directory` when the path is in fact correct i.e., `ls /var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java /var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java`. My startup script contains:

`export JAVA_HOME=/var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31`
`export JRE_HOME=/var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31`

When I run: `eval /var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin` I get: `/var/www/path/to/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin: Is a directory` but eval on anything inside this directory returns No such file or directory.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Check the permissions on those files; sounds like a permissions issue to me.

Comment: I tried that with no luck. Installing these: lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 got me aliitle further but now I'm getting: org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8989"]
May 6, 2014 2:34:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]...

Comment: I think these new errors are from low memory because I'm running tomcat in a vm.

Comment: Check the catalina.out e.g. If your guess is right, you will find some clues there.

Comment: Not sure what these mean: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)...

Comment: I guess this is not the case because I did an install on my Mac - no vm and I'm getting the same errors.